# How to take search service application Backup? Can only Index taken as backup and restored?

Tags: search, enterprise-search, backup, 2016, farm-admin

Team,

we have live application set-up in which we are using SharePoint search service application. what is the best way to take up back-up and restore the same?

I read from  [Technet Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748635.aspx) that  Below cmdlets can be used.

> Backup-SPFarm -Directory  -BackupMethod {Full | Differential} -Item "Farm\Shared Services\Shared Services Applications\" [-Verbose]

My question is that is this the only way to restore search service application  or can we take only Index backup and restore it? If that index backup and restore is possible - how to do that?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the link you provided. The backup procedure is to take a Full backup (which also does an Index Backup) then perform subsequent Differentials (which also does a full index backup).

You need to separately backup your Thesaurus File, it is not included in the backup.

Restoration of the backup is done with:
`Restore-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -Item "<ServiceApplicationName>" -RestoreMethod Overwrite [-BackupId <GUID>] [-Verbose]`

[Restore Search Service Application](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee748654.aspx)

Another interesting approach is to use VSS to perform this task. [How to: Back up and restore a search service application in SharePoint 2013 using VSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn411564.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information. I'll try this and update you. BTW, your videos are insightful and helpful. Please continue your good work of sharing with communities.